# Using Double Pointers after memory allocated within function

Tags: c, pointers

I was playing with double pointers in C and was wondering if I create a function that initializes the table, it crashes on going back to main when I try to make use of the memory allocated by InitStringTable. I believe a simple fix is to make strTable global and then I believe its OK, but I prefer not to do so as this is more of a learning exercise for me in passing the table around for modification i.e. I should be able to modify strTable from main or another function modifyTable after InitStringTable.
 Thanks for any help you can give.

```
int main()
{
    char** strTable;

    // Allocates memory for string table.
    InitStringTable(strTable);
    // Below lines should be able to copy strings into newly allocated table.
    // Below lines cause crash however.
    strcpy(strTable[0], "abcdef");

    strcpy(strTable[1], "xy");
}

// Allocates memory for the string table. This function should create a table
// of size 10 strings with each string 50 chars long. The code compiles fine.
void InitStringTable(char** table)
{
   int i = 0;

   table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      table[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      memset(table[i], 0, 50);
   }

   strcpy(table[0], "string1");
}
```

Comment: Other than the fact you cast `malloc` (which you should not do in C), how is this related to C++ where you should be using `std::string`, `std::vector`, and not using raw pointer?

Comment: It looks like you need to change `table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);` to `table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);`, seeing as `table` is an array of `char *`.

Comment: Why is your function void? Why not use the return value for something useful?

Comment: Indirection madness... if you want `InitStringTable` to change the variable you pass as an argument, you'll have to pass a pointer to that variable, ie: `&strTable`, which means you'll have to change `InitStringTable` to take `char ***table`. But really: three levels of indirection is not what you want

Comment: Yes this should not be C++. My mistake. And yes I should be allocating for char* and not char. Looks like I can either return char** or take in char*** to fix my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C is pass by value.

The value assigned to `table` is lost on returning from `InitStringTable()`.

---

Also when allocating pointers to `char` ask for room for pointers to `char`.

So this:

```
... = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

shall at least be (assuming C):

```
... = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
```

---

A possible approach to this would be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int InitStringTable(char *** ppptable, const size_t n, const size_t l)
{
   int result = 0;

   if (NULL == ppptable)
   {
     result = -1;
     errno = EINVAL;
   }
   else
   {
     (*ppptable) = malloc(n * sizeof(**ppptable));
     if (NULL == (*ppptable))
     {
       result = -1;
     }
     else
     {
       size_t i = 0;
       for(; i < n; ++i)
       {
         (*ppptable)[i] = calloc(l, sizeof(*(*ppptable)[i]));
         if (NULL == (*ppptable)[i])
         {
           result = -1; 

           /* Failing in the middle requires clean-up. */
           for (; i > 0; --i)
           {
             free((*ppptable)[i-1]);
           }

           free(*ppptable); 
           (*ppptable) = NULL;

           break;
         }
       }
     }
   }

   return result;
 }
```

Call it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int InitStringTable(char *** ppptable, const size_t n, const size_t l);

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  char ** strTable = NULL;

  if ( -1 == InitStringTable(&strTable, 10, 42)) //* Allocate array with 10 "strings" à 42 chars. */
  {
    perror("InitStringTable() failed");
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(strTable[0], "abcdef");
    strcpy(strTable[1], "xy");
  }

  return result;
}
```

And no, I won't get into this ridiculous "You don't wanna be a 3-star-programmer!" discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes I made a mistake in the code in allocating a array of char where it should've been array of char*. Your solution is elegant as I forgot to add the NULL checking after calls to malloc as well. The char *** may look funny, but I think it helps reinforce that C is call by value by default which I had forgotten in coding this case. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to free strTable[*] and strTable at the end of main(), since its memory has been allocated with malloc/calloc ? I have a bit of difficulty to understand exactly when do I need free pointers when memory is allocated in another function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer issue.

It's like if you say:

```
void inc(int a){
    a++;
}

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    inc(a);
    printf ("%d\n", a); // will display 0, not 1
}
```

does not work.

You must pass `&strTable` instead of `strTable` as `InitStringTable` argument, and change other things in `InitStringTable` consequently ..
Or just do `strTable = InitStringTable()`; , and return a `char**` from `InitStringTable`.

Comment: eh... why no indention?

Answer (score 0):

The lines below InitStringTable() crash, because they are trying to perform operations 
on a memory address that is neither in the same scope as theirs nor have any reference to
that memory address.

The function InitStringTable() allocates memory to the table, but cannot be accessed by the
calling function (here main), because the memory is local to the function in which it
allocated.
Therefore in order  to use the same memory address for operations in the
calling function you must pass a reference of that address to the calling function.

In your program you can do it as under :
Declare the function as :-

```
char **InitStringTable(char **);


int main()
{
    char** strTable;
    strTable = InitStringTable(strTable);   
    strcpy(strTable[0], "abcdef");   
    strcpy(strTable[1], "xy");
}   

char **InitStringTable(char** table)
{
   int i = 0;

   table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      table[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      memset(table[i], 0, 50);
   }

   strcpy(table[0], "string1");


   /* after the function has finished its job, return the address of the table */    
   return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution as well. I see merit in returning char**, but I see further understanding from having a char*** argument.