# How can I malloc a struct array inside a function? Code works otherwise

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, struct

I'm trying to create a function that creates a variable sized 2D funct array. I'm using the following code, which seems to work just fine on its own:

```
typedef struct
{
    //Starter Properties
    int TypeB;
    int TypeF;
    int TypeW;
    //Randomized Properties
    int RandB;
    int RandF;
    int RandW;
    //Derived Properties
    int Speed;
} MapTileData;

MapTileData **Map;

int i, x=5, y=5;

//Allocate Initial Space
Map = (MapTileData**)calloc(x, sizeof(MapTileData));

for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    Map[i] = (MapTileData*)calloc(y, sizeof(MapTileData));
}
```

So the above code creates a 2D struct array. My attempts to move the code to a function have been less successful, giving segmentation faults when trying to print the array:

```
void CreateMap(MapTileData **Map, int xSize, int ySize)
{
    //Variables
    int i;

    //Allocate Initial Space
    Map = (MapTileData**)calloc(xSize, sizeof(MapTileData));

    for(i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
        {
            Map[i] = (MapTileData*)calloc(ySize, sizeof(MapTileData));
        }
}
```

Used in the code:

```
MapTileData **MapTile;

CreateMap(MapTile,5,5);
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you do `void f(int i) {i = /* something */;}`, why doesn't it change `i` outside the function?

Comment: Unrelated, but `sizeof(MapTileData)` should be `sizeof(MapTileData*)` in the first `calloc` call.

Comment: More or less a duplicate to allocating a "string"-array, (which in fact is as "2d-array" of `char`) inside a function: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25769443/694576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments are *passed by value* in C and modifying arguments in callee won't affect caller's local variables.

Use pointers to modify caller's local variables.

```
void CreateMap(MapTileData ***Map, int xSize, int ySize)
{
    //Variables
    int i;

    //Allocate Initial Space
    *Map = calloc(xSize, sizeof(MapTileData));

    for(i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
    {
        (*Map)[i] = calloc(ySize, sizeof(MapTileData));
    }
}
```

Usage in the code:

```
MapTileData **MapTile;

CreateMap(&MapTile,5,5);
```

Alternate way: Pass the allocated array via the return value.

```
MapTileData **CreateMap(int xSize, int ySize)
{
    //Variables
    MapTileData **Map;
    int i;

    //Allocate Initial Space
    Map = calloc(xSize, sizeof(MapTileData));

    for(i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
    {
        Map[i] = calloc(ySize, sizeof(MapTileData));
    }

    //Return the value
    return Map;
}
```

Usage in the code:

```
MapTileData **MapTile;

Maptile = CreateMap(5,5);
```

Also note that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` and its family in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Up'ed, assuming you left out all error checking for the sake of readability ... ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I read up on using pointers in functions, I think I understand it a little better now. Cheers!