# wrong output in singly linked list in c

Tags: c, struct

I need a help. I tried to create a singly linked list. Everything is fine so far,but I got a wrong output. I have no idea about my mistake. Thank you!

My output is :

```
 create a single linked list
 list:
 aaaaa
 -1342177280
```

My code is :

```
struct node{

    int key;
    int val; 
    struct node *next;  

};

struct node *create_single_link(){

    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->next = NULL;

    return(head);

}


void insertVal( struct node *lst, int v){

    struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current -> val = v;

    current->next = lst;
    lst = current;

}

void print_list(struct node * head){


    struct node *ptr = head;

    printf("list:\n");

    while(ptr != NULL ){
        printf("aaaaa\n");
        printf("%d \n ",ptr ->val );
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }


}

int  main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    struct node *list;
    list = create_single_link();
    if(list != NULL){
        printf("create a single linked list\n");
    }
    else
        printf("failed to create a single linked list\n");

    insertVal(list,2222);
    //insertVal(list,2);
    print_list(list);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I malloc a struct array inside a function? Code works otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075244/how-can-i-malloc-a-struct-array-inside-a-function-code-works-otherwise)

Comment: Using value in buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You can read https://mortoray.com/2012/01/08/whats-an-object-whats-a-variable/, you should know the difference between `pass value` and `pass reference`.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1**

You have:

```
void insertVal( struct node *lst, int v){

    struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current -> val = v;

    current->next = lst;
    lst = current;
}
```

That does not change the value of `list` in `main`. It only change where `lst` points to locally in the function.

I suggest changing the function to:

```
struct node* insertVal( struct node *lst, int v){

    struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current -> val = v;

    current->next = lst;
    return current;
}
```

and using it as:

```
list = insertVal(list, 2222);
```

**Problem 2**

The value of the node created in `create_single_link` is left uninitialized. You are better off not using it at all. You can change `main` to:

```
int  main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   struct node *list = NULL;
   list = insertVal(list,2222);
   list = insertVal(list,2);
   print_list(list);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`insertVal` modifies `lst` but does not return it.

This means only one item can be added.

You are printing out the head with u initialised `v`

Answer (score 0):

1. A list should have its head, which points to the next element of the list. You have done the opposite: the rest of your list (the first data piece) points to the head (in `insertVal()`)
2. The head usually already stores the first piece of data; you only use head as a pointer to the rest of the list, not for storing data.
3. The reason for the erroneous behavior observed by you is that in `print_list()` you assume the opposite to my items 1. and 2. above: you try to print out the `val` associated with the head (which is against item 2 above), and you assume that the remaining list elements follow head (which is against item 1 above). *I would suggest leaving `print_list()` as is, but correcting the former two items.*
4. BTW you may consider changing the wording of your question, as your problem is not with „wrong output” but with a list implementation in C. See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html for an example implementation.
5. I am skipping for now that your `struct node` has two fields (`key` and `val`) yet your `insertVal()` only fills `vall`. While not an error per se, it is dangerous as sooner or later you will forget to assign a meaningful value to `key`.
   Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your fucntion insert value doesn't make any sense, if you mean to insert a value in the end of the linked list, I hope the code below can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int key;
    int val;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *create_single_link() {
struct node *head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->next = NULL;
return (head);
}

void insertVal (struct node *lst, int v) {
while(lst->next != NULL) {
    lst = lst->next;
}
lst->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
lst->next->val = v;
lst->next->next = NULL;
}

void print_list(struct node *ptr) {
while(ptr != NULL) {
    printf("the key is %d and the value is %d\n", ptr->key, ptr->val);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
}


void main(void) {

struct node *list;
list = create_single_link();
if(list != NULL) 
    printf("a single list has been created\n");
else
    printf("faied to create a single list\n");
list->val = 1111;
insertVal(list, 2222);
insertVal(list, 3333);
print_list(list);
}
```