# Pointer to array of pointers returns to initial address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm looking at this small program that creates a shell. `parse()` takes a character pointer `line` and an array of character pointers `argv`, saving the address of each word in `argv`.

```
void  parse(char *line, char **argv) {
 while (*line != '\0') {       /* if not the end of line ....... */
      while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
           *line++ = '\0';     /* replace white spaces with 0    */
      *argv++ = line;          /* save the argument position     */
      printf("%p\n",*argv);
      while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&
             *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
           line++;             /* skip the argument until ...    */
 }
 *argv = '\0';                 /* mark the end of argument list  */
}
```

What I don't understand is that `argv` is somehow back at the first word after the function exits. The main function calls:

```
parse(line, argv);       /*   parse the line               */
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)  /* is it an "exit"?     */
           exit(0);
```

How is `argv[0]` at the beginning of `line` when it was at the end of `line` right before?

Comment: `*argv = '\0'; `, `argv` is a pointer to string not a string, do you mean `*argv = NULL`?

Comment: See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/25769443/694576 if not a duplicate to the latter.

Comment: @AlterMann probably, although OP code does work because `'\0'` is identical to `0` (i.e. an `int` with value zero)

Comment: @M.M, yes, `NULL` and 0 are interchangeable in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that parameters are passed by value in C. Think of it this way:

```
void func(int a)
{
     a = 20;
}

int main()
{
     int val = 10;
     printf("%d", val);
     func(val);
     printf("%d", val);
}
```

In both the prints above, the value printed out would be 10. If you want to modify val in func then you would have to pass its address. Same is true with pointers. Pointers are passed-by-value just like any other parameter. Thus, if you have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char **argv)
{
  while (*argv != 0) {
    printf("%s\n", *argv);
    argv++;
  } 
  printf("*****done*****\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  func(argv);
  printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

And you run it with:

```
gcc a.c
./a.out hello how are you
```

Output would be:

```
./a.out
hello
how
are
you
*****done*****
./a.out
```

If you want argv to point to the last parameter when it returns back from the function, then you would have to pass its address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char ***argv)
{
  while (**argv != 0) {
    printf("%s\n", **argv);
    (*argv)++;
  } 
  (*argv)--;
  printf("*****done*****\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  func(&argv);
  printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

And now the output would be:

```
./a.out
hello
how
are
you
*****done*****
you
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand where the confusion is, when you call `void  parse(char *line, char **argv)` sending the `line` and `argv` pointers to the function, the function receives a *COPY* of each pointer with each copy having an address all its own.

So regardless what your do to the pointer itself within the function (e.g. iterate over the `argv` by `argv++, argv++`, those changes are never seen in `main()` because the increment is only happening to the *copy* of the argument vector and the *original pointer* back in `main` has no clue about any of it.

Now if you change the contents of any of the individual strings in `argv`, those changes will be seen back in `main`, but any other non-content modifying changes are local to your function only.

The only way you can change the pointer in your function is to *pass the address-of* your pointer to the function. That would give you a prototype of `void  parse(char **line, char ***argv)` Then you can change the pointer iself in your function and have those changes visible in `main` (e.g. `char *tmp = (*argv)[0]; (*argv)[0] = (*argv)[1]; (*argv)[1] = tmp;`)